# Finding Perfect Numbers Using Functions and Preset Code

Tags: c

I'm kind of a new programmer here. I'm trying to write a program that will print perfect numbers between a range of 1-10,000, and list all of numbers that are divisible by the perfect number. I was given a preset of code and the bottom is what I currently have. What am I doing wrong (barring any syntax)?

```
#include <stdio.h>  
int perfect(int); 
void list_perfect(int);
int main() {
    int i;     
    for (i=2; i<10000; i++) {
        if (perfect(i)) {
            list_perfect(i);
        }
    return 0;
}


int perfect(int number) {
}
void list_perfect(int number) {    
}
```

current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int perfect(int);
void list_perfect(int);
int main() {
    int i;
    for (i=2; i<10000; i++) {
        if (perfect(i)) {                 
            printf("These are the perfect numbers:\n");
            list_perfect(i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int perfect(int number) { 
    int sum;
    int k;
    sum = 0;
    for (k=2; k<number; k++) {
        if(number%k==0) {
            sum += k;
        }
    }
    if(sum == number)
        return sum;
    else
        return 0;
    }
}

void list_perfect(int number) {
    if(perfect(number)) {
        printf("%d", number);
    }
}
```

Comment: something is wrong here: you're computing perfect numbers twice. your `list_perfect` just does a call to `perfect` and prints it if it is.

Comment: This is not a 'debug my code for free' service!

Comment: I'm sorry I'm incompentent

Answer (score 1):

A perfect number is equal to the sum of its proper divisors. For example 6 is a perfect number and is equal to the integers 1 + 2 + 3 = 6. Since 1 is a common divisor of all proper positive integers (And Negative ones as well) I recommend you put sum = 1; inside your int perfect (int number) function above not sum = 0 to start off with, as you are starting your for loop with the 2. I am guessing this is your problem. Please make the change and see if your code will work. Thank you. Soliman.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is this line:

```
for (k=2; k<number; k++) {
```

You need to start from 1, so it should be

```
for (k=1; k<number; k++) {
```

For better performance you could do:

```
for (k=1; k <= number/2; k++) {
```

Besides that you should no call `perfect` function twice. So change this:

```
void list_perfect(int number) {
    if(perfect(number)) {
        printf("%d", number);
    }
}
```

to just a print:

```
void list_perfect(int number) {
    printf("%d ", number);
}
```

Also correct this:

```
if(sum == number)
    return sum;
else
    return 0;
}  <-------------------- Delete this line
```